# view all Excel 2010 exceptions

Tags: excel, exception, vsto

I have a VSTO Excel 2010 workbook project, and it works on all PCs except one. The additional custom user control isn't present on the workbook. I've noticed that exceptions in C# are suppressed, and I haven't found where they can be viewed. Is there such thing as Excel error log? How do I turn on all error messages?

Answer (score 3):

There are (2) error log sources that office uses when errors occur. "Microsoft Office Diagnostics" and "Microsoft Office Sessions". You can try to use these to troubleshoot.

**Office 2010**
You can enable interface error dialogs by going to File->Options->Advanced->Developers and checking "Show Add-in user interface errors".

**Office 2007**
You can enable interface error dialogs by going to Tools->Options->Other->General->Advanced Options and checking "Show Add-in user interface errors".
There is also an option to enable logging (unsure of its behavior)